# Find distinct records after a certain character

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I have a table named `dbo.cls_members` in SQL server and there is a column named `meb_refs` containing reference numbers like the following

> "A03LV4COOD17JE-**S**N1AM"

How do I find the records of the DISTINCT first character after the "-" symbol. ?

For example in the reference above the bold **"S"** after the "-".

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: Did you even try something????  If you don't even want to attempt do this, you might as well quit the profession because queries won't get any easier than this.

Comment: @Eric I apologise.  Didn't mean to upset anyone.  My SQL is very rusty and was trying to resolve several things at once and just needed to get this part done quick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps...

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(STUFF([Column],1,CHARINDEX('-',[Column]),''),1)
FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was not aware of the "Stuff" function in SQL

Answer (score 0):

Run the following query:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
      [Letter]
    FROM
    (
     SELECT 
         column_name [Code] --Step One
          ,RIGHT(column_name, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(column_name))-1) [Part after -]
          ,LEFT(RIGHT(column_name, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(column_name))-1), 1) [Letter]
       FROM table_name
    ) T
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(t.col, CHARINDEX('-',t.col)+1, 1)
FROM <yourtable> t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @nar NVARCHAR(max) = 'A03LV4COOD17JE-SN1AM'
SELECT RIGHT(left(REVERSE(@nar), CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(@nar))-1),1)
```

Alternatively, you can try:

```
SELECT * from table
where RIGHT(left(REVERSE(Columnname), CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(Columnname))-1),1)
in ('S')
```